# Is jQuery.ready useful on anything other than document?

Tags: jquery, events

I was thinking about the jQuery `$(document).ready` event and it occurs to me that I've never seen anyone apply it on anything other than `$(document)`. Is there any other legitimate use for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.

They all do the same:

> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

No, jQuery .ready() "Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded", so it cannot be used on any other element

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically, no.  Whatever you put in there, it still gets called when the DOM loaded event is fired.  For example, this:

```
$(undefined).ready(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Runs just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Note that the only other selector than `$(document).ready(` that is documented is `$().ready(` (but it's not recommended). Using any other selector is undocumented behaviour, and you can't rely on it staying the same in future versions.

Comment: No, I understand.  I didn't mean to suggest that it's recommended.